# How to make a connection to the mysql database in openshift 3.0

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I'm testing openshift 3.0 and I cannot figure out how to make a simple connection in java. I've done port forwarding: local port 3306 for remote port 3306 and I'm using the following code:

```
public class testDAO {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

            Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(
              "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sampledb","userFGF","eA3Rwe4OgSiWGeK2");
            System.out.println("Conectado!");
            conexao.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initiate connection with JDBC on OpenShift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23291743/how-to-initiate-connection-with-jdbc-on-openshift)

Comment: Can you clarify. Are you saying the MySQL database is running in OpenShift and your Java application is running on your own local computer? That is the only scenario where you would need port forwarding. For an interactive tutorial on using port forwarding with OpenShift V3, see lesson about port fowarding at https://learn.openshift.com/ Also try first to connect, if that is what you are doing, by using the ``mysql`` client rather than a Java application.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to do the port forwarding and it worked, but when I submit the web.xml settings there in the cloud the project does not work